# CSS does not load from static folder in Django with HTTP status code 200

Tags: python, css, django, http, django-staticfiles

I know this has been asked hundreds of times over the years [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081893/unable-to-serve-static-files-like-css-js-in-django-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913849/django-static-file-not-loading), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103138/receiving-404-error-when-trying-to-load-static-urls-directly-in-django) (and others) but I can't load my css files from my static folder.

- Django 1.7
- Python 2.7

My command line says

```
[07/Apr/2016 10:56:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3596
[07/Apr/2016 10:56:13] "GET /static/compile/css/fbparse.min.6d40ca4cc832.css HTTP/1.1" 200 64
[07/Apr/2016 10:56:13] "GET /static/compile/js/fbparse.min.b40ef3f82f3a.js HTTP/1.1" 200 64
```

However, my log file says

```
2016-04-07 10:45:14,333 [WARNING] django.request: Not Found: /static/compile/css/fbparse.min.6d40ca4cc832.css
2016-04-07 10:56:13,848 [WARNING] django.request: Not Found: /static/compile/css/fbparse.min.6d40ca4cc832.css
2016-04-07 10:56:13,852 [WARNING] django.request: Not Found: /static/compile/js/fbparse.min.b40ef3f82f3a.js
```

And of course, the site does not load the css file.

When I try

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/compile/css/fbparse.min.6d40ca4cc832.css
```

It gives me **error 404**

Here is what I have in settings file

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
rel = lambda *x: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, *x)

DEBUG = False

MEDIA_ROOT = rel('public', 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = rel('public', 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    rel('static_src'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

.....
)
```

Here is what I have in the Base html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load pipeline static i18n stats_tags %}
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />

    <title>My site title</title>

    {% stylesheet 'global' %}

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    {% javascript 'global' %}
    {% if debug %}
        <script src="{% static "components/less.js/dist/less.min.js" %}"></script>
        {% if LESS_DEBUG %}
            <script type="text/javascript">
                less.env = "development";
                less.watch();
            </script>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

</head>
```

I have tried putting the static folder in the root directory, inside public, inside static_src but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually have the file in your `static` folder?

Comment: Yes. I have checked many times to make sure I have that. Also checked if the contents are correct - file names are correct etc. All is there..

Comment: for you static file settings.. try these  `STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')`

`STATIC_URL = '/static/' # You may find this is already defined as such.`

`STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)`

Comment: and on top use `{% load staticfiles %}`.  Import static files like `"{% static "test.css" %}"`

Comment: @ManishGupta tried all that you suggested. Did not work. Based on the http error code, it seems like it might be URL.py issue but still does not get solved

Comment: can you post urls.py? But i dont think it's a problem in urls.py since you can access the link and corresponding view. It must be something in tags you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `manage.py runserver`?

In that case you want to use dev-server with `DEBUG = False`, you can simulate it via `manage.py runserver --insecure`.

If you want to deploy your django project with WAS like Apache, you need to serve your static files independently as stated in [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/).

Comment: I want to deploy. Debug = False definitely works but you can't use that for production. I have been through docs.